# Creating a locked ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm trying to implement a `ScrollView` in Android that doesn't scroll when adding an item above the current scroll position.

The default implementation of `ScrollView` behaves as following:

Adding an item **above** the current scroll position:
[image]

Adding an item **below** the current scroll position:
[image]

How can I "lock" the `ScrollView` prior to adding an item above the current scroll position?

This is my layout file, I've currently overridden both the `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout`, but haven't made any alterations yet.

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Add To Top"
            android:onClick="addToStart">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add to End"
            android:onClick="addToEnd">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.poc.scroller.locable.lockablescrollerpoc.LockedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:background="@color/scrollColor">

        <com.poc.scroller.locable.lockablescrollerpoc.LockedLinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/Container">
        </com.poc.scroller.locable.lockablescrollerpoc.LockedLinearLayout>

    </com.poc.scroller.locable.lockablescrollerpoc.LockedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Example Source Code:**
https://github.com/Amaros90/android-lockable-scroller-poc

Thank you!

Comment: provide layout snippet pls

Comment: Try calling scroll to top and scroll to bottom on button click

Comment: @AjayVenugopal what you're suggesting will be give the app flaky behaviour

Comment: @surajshinde done!

Comment: Is there a particular reason, that you are using a ScrollView? Using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) would be my approach, since its used for something like your problem.

Comment: @PatrickZinner I'm working with Amaros - we want to use FlatList of React Native and it accepts only ScrollView as scroller. We are open to new ideas as well - how will using RecyclerView solve our problem? Is there a way to do it with ScrollView?

Comment: I don't know about the ScrollView. But you can use a RecyclerView.
 You will have to use a LayoutManager and in your case a [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html). You can use the `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` and `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` methods to find the right positions, where you want to insert your item. Then you call the Adapters method 'RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemInserted(int position)' to notify the View that it should refresh.

Comment: @PatrickZinner Unfortunately, this feature has to be implemented for a ScrollView. Do you think it's even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing this worked for me. You can check out the example app I added in the original question.

```
public class LockableScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private boolean _enabled = true;

    public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        super.setFillViewport(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(layout, params);

        ((ViewGroup)layout).setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new OnHierarchyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildViewAdded(View layout, View item) {
                if (_enabled) {
                    item.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLayoutChange(View item, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                        item.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

                        int scrollViewY = ((LockableScrollView)item.getParent().getParent()).getScrollY();
                        int layoutPosition = ((View)item.getParent()).getTop();
                        boolean shouldScroll = item.getTop() + layoutPosition <= scrollViewY || item.getBottom() + getTop() <= scrollViewY;



                        if (shouldScroll) {
                            final int childViewHeight = item.getHeight();

                            ((View)item.getParent()).addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLayoutChange(View layout, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                                    layout.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

                                    LockableScrollView scrollView = ((LockableScrollView)layout.getParent());
                                    scrollView.scrollTo(scrollView.getScrollX(), scrollView.getScrollY() + childViewHeight);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildViewRemoved(View layout, View item) {
                if (_enabled) {
                    int scrollViewY = ((LockableScrollView)layout.getParent()).getScrollY();
                    int layoutPosition = layout.getTop();
                    boolean shouldScroll = item.getTop() + layoutPosition <= scrollViewY || item.getBottom() + getTop() <= scrollViewY;


                    if (shouldScroll) {
                        final int childViewHeight = item.getHeight();

                        layout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLayoutChange(View layout, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                                layout.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

                                LockableScrollView scrollView = ((LockableScrollView)layout.getParent());
                                scrollView.scrollTo(scrollView.getScrollX(), scrollView.getScrollY() - childViewHeight);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can easily get the opposite behavior by using `addOnLayoutChangeListener` of your `LinearLayout` and reset the `ScrollView`'s `ScrollY`. Here is the implementation in your `ScrollViewActivity.onCreate`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scrollview);

    _linearLayout = (LockedLinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Container);
    _scrollView = (LockedScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView);
    _layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    _linearLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            _scrollView.scrollTo(0, _scrollView.getScrollY() + (bottom - oldBottom ));
        }
    });

    addExampleImage(10, _linearLayout);
}
```

Then you can easily flag the `addToEnd` function or check where the child was added to avoid changing scroll when some child is added to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `RecyclerView` and  implement `onDataSetChanged()`. Then detect whether `add to TOP` or `add to END` button was pressed. Then use [`scrollToPositionWithOffset(int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int)) to manage the scroll.

**For example:**

```
//Scroll item 3 to 20 pixels from the top
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(3, 20);
```

For restoring the scroll position of a `RecyclerView`, this is how to save the scroll positions (the two arguments for the method `scrollToPositionWithOffset(int, int)`):

```
int index = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); 
View v = linearLayoutManager.getChildAt(0); 
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - linearLayoutManager.getPaddingTop())
```

Comment: When using `RecyclerView` you can call this function, and the scroll will not change
_flagsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
But we still need to implement this feature with `ScrollView` and not with `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily just get it..

first of all in onclick event store the int value by 
using getFirstVisiblePosition()

example.

in ***onclick of add element button do this---***

> int currentpos = recycleview.getFirstVisiblePosition();

***now after you insert elment to list/recyclerview---***

> recyclerview.scrolltoposition(currentpos);

thats it try if you want to do it without error..

Good Luck :)